# Using Angular 2.0 or React without changing our build process?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, web

I want to begin using a front-end framework in a very large legacy codebase (just some widgets at first) but with minimal changes to the build process. Management wants to try this but it's low priority and we have more important things going on, so whatever I do can't hassle other developers.

With Vue and Angular 1.X I can just include a JavaScript file and begin coding. Is it possible to do something similar with Angular 2.0 (which seems to require node.js and a tool like webpack on the build server) or React? And if not, what's the best way to use them and have the least effect on other developers? Thanks for any help.

Comment: My way is the best way and not the best way the other guy said but he disagrees with the third guy. Get it? Don't ask for opinions on SO, a fact based platform.

Comment: I’m not trying to ask for the best way, I’m asking if it’s possible at all. The normal way of doing things is clear, but not an option for me.

Comment: "...what's the best way to use them and ..."

Comment: “Is it possible...” was my primary question that you ignored. That one was a follow-up.

Answer (score 1):

For React to properly work, you will need a **package-manager**, a **bundler** and a **compiler** (e.g. yarn/npm, webpack & babel), see also [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/installation.html#adding-react-to-an-existing-application). You can write React in plain Javascript but it's not recommended.

Regarding the integration: you should test the new framework with a small, isolated widget first and the slowly transform the rest of your code.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping I might be able to import a version of React that was usable out of the box, but it appears not. I’m going to look into SFX Angular 2.0 and it’s pros and cons.